# converting key,value list to dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a list in this format got from another datasource

```
      a=[{'prod':'product1','price':100},{'prod':'product2','price':200}]
```

if i run a for loop to get into a dict. i get only the last item. how to append each item to the dictionary as i run thru for loop

i want a final output like this

```
 z={0:{'prod':'product1','price':100},
    '1':{'prod':'product2','price':200}
   }
```

or

```
  z={'0':{'product1':100},
     '1':{'product2':200}
    }
```

what i tried

thanks

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: @vanakkam `for num in range(len(a)):`.  The `0` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
z = {}
for i in len(a):
 z[i] = a[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and `enumerate` to get the index and value from `a`:

```
>>> {i: v for i,v in enumerate(a)}
{0: {'price': 100, 'prod': 'product1'}, 1: {'price': 200, 'prod': 'product2'}}
>>> {i: {v['prod']:v['price']} for i,v in enumerate(a)}
{0: {'product1': 100}, 1: {'product2': 200}}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to make this into dictionary as i still get as set. z={i:v for i,v in enumerate(a)} and i print z it gives as set. i am not familiar with Dict Comprehension